# adding login functionality to my project in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have registeration form which redirects to listing page. Now i want to add login functionality to my page and after login my page should show respective users form autofilled. But i didnt get how to use it please help.

controller

```
function login(){
    $this->load->view('login_form.php');
}
function check_login(){ 
    if($_POST) {
        $result = $this->Student_info_model->validate_user($_POST);
        if(!empty($result)) {
            $data = ['id' => $result->user,'name' => $result->name ];
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('home');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_data', 'Username or password is wrong!');
            redirect('Student_info/login');
        }
 }
```

Model

```
public function validate_user($data) {
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->where('name', $data['name']);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($data['password']));
    return $this->db->get('student_info_table')->row();
}
```

View

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Student_info/check_login');?>"method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
    <label for="password">password</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" /><br>
    <input type="submit"  value="login"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

**The Controller**

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $this->load->model('login_model');
  
 }
 public function index()
 {
  if(($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==1) && ($this->session->userdata('role')==1))
  {
   redirect(base_url('admin/dashboard'),'refresh');
  }
  if(($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==1) && ($this->session->userdata('role')==2))
  {
   redirect(base_url('teacher/dashboard'),'refresh');
  }
  if(($this->session->userdata('logged_in')==1) && ($this->session->userdata('role')==2))
  {
   redirect(base_url('student/dashboard'),'refresh');
  }
  $data['title']='User Login';
  $this->load->view('login',$data);
 }
 
 public function login_action()
 {
  
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('userpassword', 'Password', 'trim|required');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->session->set_flashdata('user-error', 'Username or password are incorrect !');
   redirect(base_url().'user');
  }
  else
  {
     $data = array(
      'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
      'password' => $this->input->post('userpassword')
      );
   $result =$this->login_model->userlogin($data); 
   if ($result == TRUE)
    {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $result = $this->login_model->get_userinfo($username);     
    if ($result != false) {
    $session_data = array(
    'userid' => $result[0]->userid,
    'username' => $result[0]->username,
    'email' => $result[0]->email,
    'role'=>$result[0]->role,
    'logged_in'=>1
    );
    $role=$result[0]->role;
    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
    if($role=='1')
    {
     redirect(base_url().'admin/dashboard');
    }
    if($role=='2')
    {
     $this->load->view('teacher');
    }
    if($role=='3')
    {
     $this->load->view('student');
    }      
     } 
    }
    else
    {
     $this->session->set_flashdata('user-error', 'Username or password are incorrect!');
     redirect(base_url().'user');
    }
  }
 }
 
 public function logout()
 {
  $this->session->sess_destroy();
  $this->session->set_flashdata('user-out','You have been logout Successfully');
  redirect(base_url().'user');
 }
 
}
```

**The Model**

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class login_model extends CI_Model
{
 public function __contruct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->database();
 }
 
 public function userlogin($data)
 {
 $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('user');
 $this->db->where($condition);
 $this->db->limit(1);
 $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows() == 1)
  {
   return true;
  }
  else 
  {
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 public function get_userinfo($username)
 {
  $condition = "username =" . "'" . $username . "'";
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('user');
  $this->db->where($condition);
  $this->db->limit(1);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
  return $query->result();
  } else {
  return false;
  }
 }
}
```

**The View**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title ?></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----webfonts--->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!---//webfonts--->  
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="login">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
  <h2 class="form-heading">login</h2>  
  <div class="app-cam">
  <?php
  if($this->session->flashdata('user-out')) { echo '<p class="text-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user-out').'</p>';}
  if($this->session->flashdata('user-error')) { echo '<p class="text-danger">'.$this->session->flashdata('user-error').'</p>';} ?>
   <form action="<?php echo base_url(),'user/login_action'; ?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="username" class="text" value="E-mail address" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail address';}">
  <input type="password" name="userpassword" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}">
  <div class="submit"><input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" value="Login"></div>
  <div class="login-social-link">
          <a href="" class="facebook">
              Facebook
          </a>
          <a href="" class="twitter">
              Twitter
          </a>
        </div>
  <ul class="new">
   <li class="new_left"><p><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p></li>
   <li class="new_right"><p class="sign">New here ?<a href=""> Sign Up</a></p></li>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </ul>
 </form>
  </div>
   <div class="copy_layout login">
      <p>Copyright &copy; 2015 Modern. All Rights Reserved | Design by <a href="http://w3layouts.com/" target="_blank">W3layouts</a> </p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```